# ¿Cómo hacer un trigger update en mysql?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Muy buenas, tengo el problema que al hacer el insert en la tabla pedidos se me bloquea la tabla productos, lo que necesito hacer es que se actualice el stock en la tabla productos al ingresar datos en la tabla pedido. Lo estoy haciendo de la siguiete froma:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_stock AFTER INSERT ON pedido
FOR EACH ROW
Update productos set productos.stock = (productos.stock - pedido.cantidad)
where productos.Id_producto = pedido.Id_producto;
```

el script de las tablas es este

```
CREATE TABLE `Productos` (
  `Id_producto` int,
  `Descripcion` Varchar(80),
  `Precio` float,
  `Stock` int,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id_producto`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Pedido` (
  `No_Pedido` int,
  `Descripcion` varchar(100),
  `Precio` float,
  `Cantidad` smallint,
  `Total` float,
  `Cancelado` float,
  `SaldoProducto` int,
  `Id_producto` int,
  `Id_cliente` int,
  `Id_regdir` int,
  PRIMARY KEY (`No_Pedido`),
  KEY `FK` (`Id_producto`, `Id_cliente`, `Id_regdir`)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que veo mal es que en tu `Trigger`, al hacer la consulta llamas en **minúscula (pedido)** tu tabla, cuando de verdad la tienes en **Mayúscula (Pedido)**, en general en todo tu `Trigger` está de esa forma.

Otra cosa es que no le pasas la `cantidad` que se estaría insertando como `NEW` ni mucho menos el `Id_producto` de ese Pedido. Debería quedar así:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER update_stock AFTER INSERT ON Pedido
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
Update Productos set Productos.Stock = (Productos.Stock - NEW.Cantidad)
where Productos.Id_producto = NEW.Id_producto;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: En efecto, tengo muchos errores, me está costando un poco pero aprendo rápido, muchas gracias!